# Плагин для wordpress, позволяющий загружать аудио с youtube

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Может кто-то встречал плагин для wordpress, который автоматически будет добавлять кнопку для загрузки аудио в каждый пост, содержащий видео с youtube после его публикации? Видел на одном из ресурсов, что есть реализация кнопки для загрузки видео, если оно с youtube, путем добавления js кода, но как это реализовать на wordpress не знаю. Я не прошу, чтобы мне написали готовое решение, интересно, возможно ли это реализовать в принципе и в каком направлении думать. 
Скрипт взят с ресурса savefrom.net и добавляет кнопку для загрузки видео с youtube на сайт:

// Вставка скрипта: (function(w, d, s, p, a, c) { w.sfButton = w.sfButton || function(){}; c = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; a = d.createElement(s); a.async=1; a.src=p; c.parentNode.insertBefore(a, c); })(window, document, 'script', '//savefrom.net/js/sf-helper-agent.min.js'); // Текст: sfButton.text = 'Скачать'; // Cтили: sfButton.styles = { color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)', textShadow: '1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)', fontFamily: 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif', fontSize: '12px', backgroundColor: '#81c200', border: 'none' };

Comment: Ну а какие проблемы подключить js скрипт с помощью wp_enqueue_script()

Comment: Спасибо, программисты прикрутили скрипт, но проблема теперь в том, что при нажатии на кнопку загружается видео. Сейчас стоит задача, как эту ссылку для загрузки видео с канала youtube передать на онлайн конвертер, чтобы оттуда уже подтянуть ссылку на загрузку mp3.

Comment: Пусть прикрутят тот скрипт, который загружает не видео, а аудио. Не видя ни сайта, ни скриптов, ни примера - как можно дать ответ?

Comment: <script>
// Вставка скрипта:
(function(w, d, s, p, a, c) {
w.sfButton = w.sfButton || function(){};
c = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
a = d.createElement(s);
a.async=1;
a.src=p;
c.parentNode.insertBefore(a, c);
})(window, document, 'script', '//savefrom.net/js/sf-helper-agent.min.js');

// Текст:
sfButton.text = 'Скачать';

// Cтили:
sfButton.styles = {
 color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
 textShadow: '1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
 fontFamily: 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
 fontSize: '12px',
 backgroundColor: '#81c200',
 border: 'none'
};
</script>

Comment: это скрипт, который добавляет кнопку загрузки видео с youtube на сайт. Все это на основе ресурса savefrome.net

Comment: Вставьте это в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка Править.